# How to synchronously call a method after dispatching an action in Angular with NRGX

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I have a method that dispatches an action, then triggers an effect, then triggers a service, that service will catch/handle an error that triggers an action.

My problem is when I dispatch an action, the error handler on the service will update the state but when I log the state it's still in the old state. However on the ngOnInit when I subscribed the state has been updated. I'm unfamiliar with the flow because it has rxjs but I think if I can make the dispatch work like a promise then I could wait for it and then execute a method after it's done.

Here's the code where it's being triggered on ngOnInit:

```js
 setupFailedAddToCartStatus() {
    combineLatest(
      this.store.select(getAddToCartFailedStatus),
      this.store.select(getAddToCartFailedMsg)
    )
      .pipe(
        map(
          ([addToCartFailedStatus, addToCartFailedMsg]: [boolean, string]) => {
            console.log('checkout.component - NgOninit - line: 385');
            this.addToCartFailedStatus = addToCartFailedStatus;
            this.addToCartFailedMsg = addToCartFailedMsg;

            this.addToCartFailedStatus$.next(addToCartFailedStatus);
            this.addToCartFailedMsg$.next(addToCartFailedMsg);
            console.log({ addToCartFailedStatus, addToCartFailedMsg });
          }
        )
      )
      .subscribe();
  }
```

This is the code where the dispatch action is being triggered and eventually triggers a service.

```js
 addToCart() {
    combineLatest(
      this.store.select(getAddToCartFailedStatus),
      this.store.select(getAddToCartFailedMsg),
      this.product$,
      this.variantId$,
      this.specTemplateStatusAndValue$.pipe(
        map((statusAndValue) => statusAndValue.value)
      )
    )
      .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$),
        first(),
        flatMap(
          ([
            addToCartFailedStatus,
            addToCartFailedMsg,
            product,
            variantId,
            specTemplateValue
          ]) => {
            this.store.dispatch(   <-----------this is the part where the action is being executed, but the logs below this method will be triggered first before the state can be updated.
              this.checkoutActions.addToCart(
                variantId,
                product.normal_product ? 1 : 1,
                specTemplateValue,
                []
              )
            );

            console.log(
              addToCartFailedStatus,
              'checkout.component - addToCart - line: 1415'
            );
            if (addToCartFailedStatus) return of(null);
            console.log('checkout.component - addToCart - line: 1417');
            // return this.router.navigate(['/checkout', 'cart']);
            return of(addToCartFailedStatus);
          }
        )
      )
      .subscribe(() => {
        console.log(
          this.addToCartFailedStatus$.value,
          'checkout.component - addToCart - line: 1433'
        );
        if (this.addToCartFailedStatus$.value) return of(null);
        console.log(
          this.addToCartFailedStatus$.value,
          'checkout.component - addToCart - line: 1435'
        );
        // return this.router.navigate(['/checkout', 'cart']);
      });
  }
```

Logs:

[image]

As you can see in the logs line 390 is being triggered on the initialization of the component which is expected.

But then after initialization, a button is clicked, then lines 1415, 1417, 1433, and 1435  are being run with the old state, not the updated state.

The updated state are seen on line 390, which is set up by ngOninit.

What I'm trying to achieve is run this code:

```js
this.store.dispatch(
              this.checkoutActions.addToCart(
                variantId,
                product.normal_product ? 1 : 1,
                specTemplateValue,
                []
              )
            );
```

after the API/Service is done executing lines 1415, 1417, 1433, and 1435 should run.

Answer (score 1):

A short and completely useless answer for your question:

```
console.log(
              addToCartFailedStatus,
              'checkout.component - addToCart - line: 1415'
            );
```

the reason this code will always log `false` is because you have `first()` operator before `flatmap`. `this.store.select(getAddToCartFailedStatus),` obviously returns `false` the first time, because you haven't even tried to add something to the shopping cart yet, and then there will be no second result coming from this stream.

So, your comment `... but the logs below this method will be triggered first before the state can be updated.` is not true. The logs are triggered as expected and the state *might be* already up to date at this point but you won't see it.

The longer answer (and somehow disappointing for you) would be: I strongly suggest you to read again about the observables, RxJs and NgRx because your current implementation is really messy from many perspectives. For example, how do you expect `addToCartFailedStatus` to be anything else than `false`? I mean, even if `dispatch` is guaranteed to be synchronously executed and update the state immediately (which is not the case), how this variable should be updated? Also, why did you decide to execute an action and immediately handle the result of its execution? NgRx is reactive, there is no guarantee that the state will be immediately updated.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your comment. tbh, I was just tasked to handle the error  (currently errors are not handled just being logged) and my senior who left wrote this code so I was having a hard time refactoring it because as soon as the addToCart method is clicked the redirect will be triggered before the dispatch is over so that's where I got confused until I read the documentation and refactor it in the state/Ngrx context instead of putting the redirect to the component. not sure if I need to post the answer but this is i think this issue is specific and I just had no experience with NGRX.